# How to change UITextField text of View2 from View1?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I'm trying to change UITextView.text from SecondViewController in ViewController. I can do it if it was NSString type in SecondViewController by doing:

```
SVC.string = @"test";
```

The problem is that:

- messageBox.text doesn't change
- SVC.messageBox.text returns (null)

One of the methods in ViewController.m:

```
    SecondViewController *SVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    SVC.messageBox.text = @"changed";
    NSLog(@"SVC: %@", SVC.messageBox.text); // result = (null)

    [self presentViewController:SVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

SecondViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *messageBox;


@end
```

SecondViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.messageBox.text = @"first";
}
```

How to get over with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is your accessing the uicontrols which are not yet created in the memory.
You have to change the order of the execution of your statements like this...

```
 SecondViewController *SVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentViewController:SVC animated:YES completion:NULL];


    SVC.messageBox.text = @"changed";
    NSLog(@"SVC: %@", SVC.messageBox.text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
 One of the methods in ViewController.m:

```
SecondViewController *SVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
SVC.strMessage= @"changed";
[self presentViewController:SVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

SecondViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
  IBOutlet UITextView *messageBox;
}
@property (nonatomic) NSString *strMessage;
@end
```

SecondViewController.m:
@synthesize strMessage;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

self.messageBox.text = strMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegates to do it as well.

Example:

Viewcontroller2nd.h

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(void) changeLabel:(NSString*)str;
@end

@interface ViewController2nd : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UIButton *bttn;
    id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

}

@property (retain) id delegate;

@end
```

Viewcontrollerone.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;

}
-(IBAction)passdata:(id)sender;

@end
```

Viewcontrollerone.m

```
-(void) changeLabel:(NSString*)str{
    lbl.text = str;
}
```

More about delegates:http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Set `@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *messageBox;` to `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *messageBox;` and check if you have connected it with `UItextView`. And don't reset it in `viewDidLoad`. Another thing you can try is:

```
SecondViewController *SVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:SVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
SVC.messageBox.text = @"changed";
NSLog(@"SVC: %@", SVC.messageBox.text); // result = (null)
```

Along with what mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

just property-synthesize string andf just assign this string to `yourTextView.text`. For example see bellow..

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController{
       NSString *strMsgText;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain)    NSString *strMsgText;
@end

@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize strMsgText;
```

after that when you present SecondViewController at that time assign your value like bellow..

```
    SecondViewController *SVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    SVC.strMsgText = @"changed";
    [SVC.strMsgText retain];


    [self presentViewController:SVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

and in `viewDidLoad:` method of `SecondViewController` just assign that string to `messageBox(TextView)`, like bellow...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     messageBox.text = strMsgText;
}
```